Ultralytics not getting installed in pycharm
I encountered an issue while attempting to reinstall the ultralytics library in PyCharm on my laptop. Despite not making any changes to my system configuration, the installation process is now failing with an error related to the GCC compiler.
This is puzzling as I had previously installed ultralytics successfully without encountering any problems. The error message suggests that there might be an issue with the GCC installation or its configuration, even though I haven't modified anything relevant.
I'll need to investigate further to determine the exact cause of the error and find a solution. This could involve checking the GCC installation for any inconsistencies, verifying its path in the environment variables, or ensuring that PyCharm's Python interpreter is configured correctly.Image of errors
> Collecting ultralytics

Using cached ultralytics-8.3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting numpy\>=1.23.0 (from ultralytics)
Using cached numpy-2.1.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
Collecting matplotlib\>=3.3.0 (from ultralytics)
Using cached matplotlib-3.9.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting opencv-python\>=4.6.0 (from ultralytics)
Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting pillow\>=7.1.2 (from ultralytics)
Using cached pillow-10.4.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Collecting pyyaml\>=5.3.1 (from ultralytics)
Using cached PyYAML-6.0.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.1 kB)
Collecting requests\>=2.23.0 (from ultralytics)
Using cached requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting scipy\>=1.4.1 (from ultralytics)
Using cached scipy-1.14.1-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of ultralytics to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting ultralytics
Using cached ultralytics-8.3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Using cached ultralytics-8.3.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Using cached ultralytics-8.3.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Using cached ultralytics-8.3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting numpy\<2.0.0,\>=1.23.0 (from ultralytics)
Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Installing backend dependencies: started
Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

\[19 lines of output\]
D:\\Coding Room\\Python.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949\\vendored-meson\\meson\\meson.py setup C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949 C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949.mesonpy-kpbmsnul -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949.mesonpy-kpbmsnul\\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.99
Source dir: C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949
Build dir: C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949.mesonpy-kpbmsnul
Build type: native build
Project name: NumPy
Project version: 1.26.4
C compiler for the host machine: gcc (gcc 6.3.0 "gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0")
C linker for the host machine: gcc ld.bfd 2.28
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 6.3.0 "c++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.28
Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.11)
Host machine cpu family: x86
Host machine cpu: x86

..\\meson.build:28:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: NumPy requires GCC \>= 8.4

A full log can be found at C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwheu7pa\\numpy_dc50f60de418499a95217a394754e949.mesonpy-kpbmsnul\\meson-logs\\meson-log.txt
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


It says "Numpy requires GCC >= 8.4" and it also says you are using gcc 6.3.0  So the solution would be to upgrade gcc, no? Btw, 6.3.0 is pretty old, version 14 is already out.

Agreed but what makes me confused is that the same library worked with this gcc only. The uninstallation and re installation of pycharm did not have any gap of even hours

I don't think this has much to do with pycharm. What might have happened is that reinstalling the python-packages caused a newer version of numpy to be installed, and that newer version may not work with your very old gcc. Python builds can be brittle like that, and mitigations include venv and pinning dependencies. In this case though, seriously just update gcc.

The obvious error is that the gcc version is too low, but something is already going "wrong" when numpy is being compiled from source on your windows machine. That means, that you are using a python version (looks like 3.13) that is not compatible with the numpy version that you need (numpy\<2.0.0,\>=1.23.0).Numpy 1.26.4 has whl files up to python 3.12.
I am guessing that you have switched to a new python version in the new setup, maybe because you have multiple and your new Pycharm picked up 3.13, while your old one was configured to use another version.
Check your setup and configure a different python version <3.13 in your project settings. Then attempt to install again
